# ElasticSearch doesn't seem to support array lookups

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I currently have a fairly simple document stored in ElasticSearch that I generated with an integration test:

```
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "unit-test_project600",
      "_type" : "recordDefinition505",
      "_id" : "400",
      "_score" : 1.0, "_source" : {
  "field900": "test string",
  "field901": "500",
  "field902": "2050-01-01T00:00:00",
  "field903": [
    "Open"
  ]
}
    } ]
  }
}
```

I would like to filter for specifically field903 and a value of "Open", so I perform the following query:

```
{
    query: {
        filtered: {
            filter: {
                term: {
                    field903: "Open",
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This returns no results. However, I can use this with other fields and it will return the record:

```
{
    query: {
        filtered: {
            filter: {
                term: {
                    field901: "500",
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It would appear that I'm unable to search in arrays with ElasticSearch. I have read a few instances of people with a similar problem, but none of them appear to have solved it. Surely this isn't a limitation of ElasticSearch?

I thought that it might be a mapping problem. Here's my mapping:

```
{
  "unit-test_project600" : {
    "recordDefinition505" : {
      "properties" : {
        "field900" : {
          "type" : "string"
        },
        "field901" : {
          "type" : "string"
        },
        "field902" : {
          "type" : "date",
          "format" : "dateOptionalTime"
        },
        "field903" : {
          "type" : "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, the [ElasticSearch docs](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/array-type/) indicate that there is no difference between a string or an array mapping, so I don't think I need to make any changes here.

Comment: There is no issue searching in arrays, it is something else.

Comment: Also please tell me these aren't the field names! Names should tell you something about the field, how would an new dev joining be able to understand this?

Comment: @ramseykhalaf: I thought someone might say this. These fields are actually custom field names generated from the database, as the user of the software is allowed to customise what fields are stored. A developer would never write a query against this; the query would be generated by the software automatically. I guess you might argue that we could generate a name for the field that involves both the primary key and the field name in some manner but I didn't feel it was necessary and was potentially fragile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try searching for "open" rather than "Open." By default, Elasticsearch uses a standard analyzer when indexing fields. The standard analyzer uses a lowercase filter, as described in the example [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/index-modules/analysis/). From my experience, Elasticsearch does search arrays.

Comment: Yes, I think analysis is probably the culprit! Think about what the field will hold. If it is free text then leave it as an analyzed string and use a `match` query (not `term`). If it is an enum-like filed, e.g.: open/closed/pending..., then used `"index": "not_analyzed"` and **make sure** you search for the **exact** string using a `term` filter.

Comment: Ah, I wasn't aware of this. You are indeed correct Scott! Thanks for drawing my attention to this.